# jQuery selection problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm trying to use the code of this example [(cropper example)](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper/tree/v0.11.1/examples/crop-avatar) of images cropper application in an [AngularJS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AngularJS) view, but it didn't work. I think the problem is in the elements selection.

This is what I'm doing:

#### Main application HTML

```
<div class="view-container layer">
    <div class="container content" ng-view>
        <!-- load the content of the view--!>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### The view

It is the code in the body section of the example [(view)](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper/blob/v0.11.1/examples/crop-avatar/index.html). I omit the whole code; I'm just including the main parts.

```
<div class="container" id="crop-avatar">
    <!-- the div content --!>
</div>
```

[**The JavaScript selectors**](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper/blob/v0.11.1/examples/crop-avatar/js/main.js)

```
function CropAvatar($element) {
    this.$container = $element;

    this.$avatarView = this.$container.find('.avatar-view');
    this.$avatar = this.$avatarView.find('img');
    this.$avatarModal = this.$container.find('#avatar-modal');
    this.$loading = this.$container.find('.loading');

    this.$avatarForm = this.$avatarModal.find('.avatar-form');
    this.$avatarUpload = this.$avatarForm.find('.avatar-upload');
    this.$avatarSrc = this.$avatarForm.find('.avatar-src');
    this.$avatarData = this.$avatarForm.find('.avatar-data');
    this.$avatarInput = this.$avatarForm.find('.avatar-input');
    this.$avatarSave = this.$avatarForm.find('.avatar-save');
    this.$avatarBtns = this.$avatarForm.find('.avatar-btns');

    this.$avatarWrapper = this.$avatarModal.find('.avatar-wrapper');
    this.$avatarPreview = this.$avatarModal.find('.avatar-preview');

    this.init();
}
```

And CropAvatar is initialized as:

```
$(function () {
    return new CropAvatar($('#crop-avatar'));
});
```

If I used the code in this form, it didn't work at all, but if I put all the HTML code into the `<body></body>` tags of mi app.html it works fine. It's for this reason that I think it is a selectors problems.

Comment: `document.ready` is worthless in an angular app using `ng-view`. None of those elements exist when the code runs. You need that code to be put in a directive

Comment: Then the solution is translate all the code to into directive code? :(

Comment: Can use the same code...just put it in a directive attached to element that would contain all the other elements. That way the code will run when the main element exists

Comment: thank I will make the test, I'm new in angular

Comment: Works perfectly THANKS!